# Como pegar dados JSON com Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

Estou estudando angular e estou tentando receber dados em formato JSON de uma webservice, mas está com o seguinte erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/newspaper/dados/jornal. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Segue meu cod abaixo.

```
app.controller("jornalCtrl", function($scope, $http) { 

    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/newspaper/dados/jornal';

    $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        params:   {
            format: 'jsonp',
            callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }
    })
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.jornais = response.jornais.jornal; 
    },
    function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.content = "Something went wrong!";
    });
});
```

Comment: Essa app do chrome vai te salvar:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: Cara eu acredito que você pode usar um protocolo HTTP direto ao invés de XMLHttpRequest pois o mesmo funciona de forma semelhante e de maneira mais pratica para conversas entre servidor e cliente;
Quando digo direto é referenciando tudo que é necessário dentro de código

Answer (score 1):

Isso dai é uma segurança fornecida pelos browsers que não te permitem fazer acesso a um servidor que não tenha permitido que você, seu host, dns, ip o consuma.

O webservice teria de habilitar para o localhost poder acessa-lo, consumir seus serviços.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa habilitar o [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (desculpa, não encontrei a mesma documentação em português) em seu serviço. Aí você vai precisar pesquisar na documentação do serviço que você está utilizando para permiti-lo, em Spring Boot por exemplo é necessário incluir a anotação:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

O controle de acesso realmente deve ser liberado no servidor. Um erro comum é tentar permitir CORS no cliente.